# How do I refresh RadGridview in Silverlight using WCF

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have written `Loadgrid()` for loading RadGridview in xaml.cs page constructor as well as on update button of child window. I am using WCF to call loadgrid(). My loadgrid() function and child window update btn code is as follows respectively

```
void loadgrid()
{
    po.GetFacilityCompleted += new EventHandler<GetFacilityCompletedEventArgs>(po_GetFacilityCompleted);
    po.GetFacilityAsync();
}

void po_GetFacilityCompleted(object sender, GetFacilityCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    radFacilityGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}

void Updatebtn_click()
{
    up.SetMessage(pp);
    up.Show();
    loadgrid();
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `radFacilityGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}` and see if you actually get some data in *e.Result* or not.

Comment: have you resolved this? Have you tried what @decyclone suggested?